# The RSS feeds are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed, hyperlinks

I'm subscribed to a couple RSS feeds from SO.com, and it seems like the titles are getting mangled in the feed.

Looking in the feed source, I see this line:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%3ftagnames%3dobjective-c%26sort%3dactive" type="text/html" />
```

When I click on the title of the feed to visit the page that originated the feed (I'm using Safari 4.0.3 on OS X 10.6.1 for reading), it attempts to take me to the URL listed in the  tag above.  Since the URL is malformed, I get a white screen of death.

The URL should be:  `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/?tagnames=objective-c&sort=active`

This started happening in the past day or so (today is 10 Oct 2009).

Any ideas what caused this or how soon it will be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sorry about that. Will be deployed and fixed in a bit.

Comment: Seems to be better now!  Thanks a bunch.  =)